# Constant warning message with reshape::melt in r

Tags: r, dataframe, warnings, reshape, melt

I am constantly getting *warning* message like :

```
as.is should be specified by the caller using true
```

Code is like :

```
difficulty_data <- data_original[,c(-1)] %>% colMeans() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% t() 
difficulty_data <- reshape::melt(difficulty_data, id.vars=c("id"))  %>% dplyr::select(-X2)
```

Description :

I wanted to calculate the **colmeans** of the dataframe and separate them in two distinct column. I deleted "X2" because in the end I wanted to plot them with ggplot.
(Result was combined with the value and the id of the value)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`.  `reshape` is an older package, compared to `reshape2` (which also include `melt`)/ or in `data.table`.  There is also `tidyr`, which have `pivot_longer`.  I would suggest to use `pivot_longer`

Comment: that looks like the warning coming from the changes to `type.convert`, eg, `type.convert('1')`, so something called by the functions you are using not by you explicitly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in the code line in `reshape::melt`

```
dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert)
```

which should be `type.convert` with `as.is = TRUE`

as in the next step it shows the warning

```
indices <- do.call(expand.grid, dn)
```

> Warning message:
> In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
> 'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE

i.e. if we look at the source code

```
 getAnywhere("melt.matrix")[1]
function (data, varnames = names(dimnames(data)), ...) 
{
    values <- as.vector(data)
    dn <- dimnames(data)
    if (is.null(dn)) 
        dn <- vector("list", length(dim(data)))
    dn_missing <- sapply(dn, is.null)
    dn[dn_missing] <- lapply(dim(data), function(x) 1:x)[dn_missing]
    char <- sapply(dn, is.character)
    dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert)
    indices <- do.call(expand.grid, dn)
    names(indices) <- varnames
    data.frame(indices, value = values)
}
```

and try to reproduce the issue with `mtcars`

```
data(mtcars)
difficulty_data <- mtcars %>%
         colMeans() %>%
         t() %>%
         as.data.frame %>% 
        t()
```

---

The data is a matrix with one column and `rownames` attribute

```
> reshape::melt(difficulty_data)
     X1 X2      value
1   mpg  1  20.090625
2   cyl  1   6.187500
3  disp  1 230.721875
4    hp  1 146.687500
5  drat  1   3.596563
6    wt  1   3.217250
7  qsec  1  17.848750
8    vs  1   0.437500
9    am  1   0.406250
10 gear  1   3.687500
11 carb  1   2.812500
Warning message:
In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE
```

As mentioned above, the fix is in adding the `type.convert` `as.is = TRUE`

```
data <- difficulty_data
varnames <- names(dimnames(data))
values <- as.vector(data)
dn <- dimnames(data)
if (is.null(dn)) 
dn <- vector("list", length(dim(data)))
dn_missing <- sapply(dn, is.null)
dn[dn_missing] <- lapply(dim(data), function(x) 1:x)[dn_missing]
      
char <- sapply(dn, is.character)
dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert, as.is = TRUE) #change here
indices <- do.call(expand.grid, dn)
names(indices) <- varnames
data.frame(indices, value = values)
          Var1 Var2      value
       1   mpg    1  20.090625
       2   cyl    1   6.187500
       3  disp    1 230.721875
       4    hp    1 146.687500
       5  drat    1   3.596563
       6    wt    1   3.217250
       7  qsec    1  17.848750
       8    vs    1   0.437500
       9    am    1   0.406250
       10 gear    1   3.687500
       11 carb    1   2.812500
```

No warnings with the fix

---

So, we may create a duplicate of the the function and change the specific line

```
meltnew <- reshape::melt.matrix
body(meltnew)[8][[1]] <- dn[char] <- lapply(dn[char], type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Now, test it

```
> meltnew(difficulty_data)
     X1 X2      value
1   mpg  1  20.090625
2   cyl  1   6.187500
3  disp  1 230.721875
4    hp  1 146.687500
5  drat  1   3.596563
6    wt  1   3.217250
7  qsec  1  17.848750
8    vs  1   0.437500
9    am  1   0.406250
10 gear  1   3.687500
11 carb  1   2.812500
```

No warnings

Comment: thank you for the effort and the time. wow it was really helpful

Comment: Since this is a generic warning I can expand the above answer: this warning may come from any other functions that depends on reshape melt.. You may get the same warning with `cSplit()` from package `splitstackshape`

Comment: @LazarusThurston yes, but here the OP used `melt` in the step `reshape::melt(difficulty_data, id.vars=c("id"))` and my answer was based on that code showed

Comment: Yes sure.. so your answer is bang on @akrun
By the way if we search for warning `type.convert`  and  `as.is = TRUE`  we land up here somehow on google. So wanted to mention a small comment if anyone else stumbles here like me.

Answer (score 0):

```r
melt(as.data.frame(difficulty_data))
```

might be also worthy of a try if anyone encountered the same problem.

Comment: This eliminates the error but drops row names

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case above, this also seems to work:

```
#make data
data(mtcars)
difficulty_data <- mtcars %>%
     colMeans() %>%
     t() %>%
     as.data.frame %>% 
    t() 

#melt data
as.data.frame.table(difficulty_data)
```